# FusedLocationProviderApi Fatal exception: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, location, google-play-services

I am a newbie android developer. I want to make a some GoogleMaps app which will show some location around user current location. But I haven't captured user location. I looked too many docs, GoogleMap Tutorials from Google. Searched from stackoverflow, but I couldn't find any solution.

There is my HaritaFragment.java

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.analytics.HitBuilders;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderApi;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.parse.FindCallback;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseGeoPoint;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class HaritaFragment extends Fragment implements LocationListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener  {

    private static GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    public static HashMap<Marker, Markers> mMarkersHashMap = new HashMap<Marker, Markers>();
    private ArrayList<Markers> mMyMarkersArray = new ArrayList<Markers>();
    private Map<Marker, Markers> allMarkersMap = new HashMap<Marker, Markers>();
    private static List<ParseObject>vetList = new ArrayList<ParseObject>();

    private LatLng latLng;
    private Double lat;
    private Double lng;



    private FusedLocationProviderApi fusedLocationProviderApi = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi;
    private static final long INTERVAL = 1000 * 10;
    private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 1000 * 5;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location userLocation;
    String mLastUpdateTime;

    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_harita, container, false);
    }

    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {

            createLocationRequest();
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();
        }
    }

        @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        //mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        stopLocationUpdates();
    }

    protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()){

            startLocationUpdates();
            setupMap();
            googleAnalyticsSendScreen();
            getAllDataFromParse();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            /*lat =  (location.getLatitude());
            lng =  (location.getLongitude());*/

        userLocation = location;
        mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.map_hibrit) {
            mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        }
        else if (id == R.id.map_standart){
            mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        }
        else if (id == R.id.map_uydu){
            mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        startLocationUpdates();
    }

    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        /*PendingResult<Status> pendingResult = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);*/

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
```

There is the logcat output :

```
06-11 17:54:43.361  17655-17855/packagename E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.
            at com.google.android.gms.internal.fp.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.common.api.w.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.internal.hy.a(Unknown Source)
            at packagename.r.P(Unknown Source)
            at packagename.r.t(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.I(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.app.w.a(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.app.w.a(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.app.e.run(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.app.w.f(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.app.w.b(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.app.ac.b(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.a(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.c(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(Unknown Source)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:13011)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4706)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:13011)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4706)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(Unknown Source)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:13011)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4706)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:13011)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4706)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1369)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:660)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:13011)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4706)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2163)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:13011)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1084)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2498)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4944)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What is the problem ? I tried 4.0.1 real HTC devices and 4.4.4 GenyMotion with GooglePlayServices.

I want to get user near locations from Parse.com and I have to capture user location for this method:

```
if (userLocation != null) {

            ParseGeoPoint parsedLocation = (new ParseGeoPoint(userLocation.getLatitude(), userLocation.getLongitude()));
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Vets");
            query.fromLocalDatastore();
            query.whereNear("location", parsedLocation);
            //query.whereWithinKilometers("location",userLocation,100);
            query.setLimit(250);
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {

                    if (e == null) {



                    } else {

                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                        builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.parse_online_query_error_title));
                        builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.parse_online_query_error_message));
                        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                        dialog.show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

If you show me the another way to do this. It would be good for me. I will not insistence for FusedLocationProviderApi.

Thank you !

Comment: I connected onStart()

Comment: so how can i connect ASYNC ?

Comment: ok. I deleted startLocationUpdates from onResume and i added the Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"lat : "+userLocation.getLatitude(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); on the onConnected() and it gives me nullpointer. Couldn't capture the userlocation.

Comment: @Selvin I wrote "I am a newbie android developer." in the begining of my question. If you want to help me please be kindly. So just tell me how can i check the user location captured ? are there any method for this isLocationCaptured or something ? Where can I put my parse query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've just got things in the wrong order. It's important to know the order Android takes when starting, pausing and resuming activities.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html

The problem in your code is when you hit `onResume` the `mGoogleApiClient` could have not quite connected.

This is the order you should have

1. Create mGoogleApiClient
2. Call mGoogleApiClient.connect();
3. onConnected() gets called automatically.

-- Call startLocationUpdates() from inside onConnected

Doing the above means your Api client is always connected when you request location updates.

I think the quickest way to fix your code is delete your `onPause` and `onResume` methods and un-comment the onDisconnect in onStop.

Allow `onStart` and `onStop` to handle your connection and the connection in turn to handle the location updates.

Best of luck.

Comment: First of all thank you for trying to help me. I reordered my methods. I just want to get parse data with user current location so where is the correct way to get parse data with user location ? ParseGeoPoint parsedLocation = (new ParseGeoPoint(userLocation.getLatitude(), userLocation.getLongitude()));

Comment: I'm not too familiar with parse, but if you just want the location, you'd put the parse details in onLocationChanged. Although this might be messy so I'd create a new method and pass the location through to fireParseRequest or something.

Comment: Also, your code requests constant location updates, from your parse code I'm wondering if you'd be better off with getLastLocation (one location) rather than requestLocationUpdates (constant updates). https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html#last-known

Comment: How can I check the location listener captured the user location or not ? I think I need a ASYNC task for this. It will wait for the user location captured and i handled the done method. I need onLocationCaptured method or something like that.

Just give me a little example when the location listener captured the user location toast it. How can u do this ?

Comment: requestLocationUpdates will give you all future good locations it can. There may be a wait for a good location. If you want one single best known location change onConnected contents to just this: LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

Comment: I want to simple parse query. When I get the user location I want to do some methods. If I put my methods on onResume() it gives me null pointer because LocationListener doesn't capture the userlocation. Because it's AYSNC task and I have to wait to capture user location when it captured the user location I will do simple Toast message "user location captured." or something. How can I check the user location captured ? I think I need a ASYNC task for user location capture process. when its done show toast message. How can I do that ?

Comment: Call your methods from onLocationChanged.